# Why are empty lists not consistently formatted in a Dataset?

Tags: front-end, formatting, dataset

> A support case with the identification [CASE:3876977] was created.

---

I just noted, that an empty list is not consistently formatted in a `Dataset`:

```
ds1 = Dataset[ Association[ "a" -> {}, "b" -> {}, "c" -> {} ] ]
```

[image: Dataset1]

```
ds2 = Dataset[ Association[ "a" -> {}, "b" -> {}, "c" -> {1,2,3} ] ]
```

[image: Dataset2]

```
ds3 = Dataset[ Association[ "a" -> {}, "b" -> {}, "c" -> Association[] ] ]
```

[image: Dataset3]

**Is this a bug or a feature the reasonability of which is escaping me at the moment? What else is formatted differently depending on other content?**

Comment: The last one convinced me that this is at least worth reporting.  A bug or not?  I do not know.  It's not a desirable result, but I had the feeling that Dataset may use heuristics to find a good formatting (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: @Szabolcs I will report this then - and accidently the third example (in a more complex application) is how I noted myself.

Comment: Looks to have something to do with the underlying ``TypeSystem` ``.  With `InputForm` you can see that there are different specifications which are resulting in different formatting. Not much information about the type system, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Dataset` visualization logic uses many heuristics to guess how a particular expression should be formatted.  The apparently inconsistent behaviour we see occurs in corner cases where multiple conflicting heuristics are applicable and one is chosen arbitrarily.  The set of heuristics, and the conflict resolution strategy, has changed from release to release.  The consequence is apparently non-deterministic behaviour.

Whether or not this is an outright bug is a matter of perspective.

**Analysis (current as of version 11.1.0)**

A helper function, `showShapes`, is defined at the bottom of this post.  It will let us explore the heuristic visualization behaviour.  We will start by examining the expressions from the question:

```
{ <| "a" -> {}, "b" -> {}, "c" -> {} |>
, <| "a" -> {}, "b" -> {}, "c" -> {1,2,3} |>
, <| "a" -> {}, "b" -> {}, "c" -> <||> |>
} // showShapes
```

*(click on the image to zoom in)*
[image: showShapes output]

This table shows each expression, along with the `Dataset` visualization, the deduced data type and a symbolical representation of the heuristically determined output "shape".

We see that the first example has been identified as an association containing vectors of unknown type and length.  The chosen shape is a column of key/value pairs with each associated value shown in a nested column of unknown shapes.

The second expression is almost the same, except that the association vector values now have a known element type: *Integer*.  On the strength of this small difference, the visualizer has elected to forgo placing the values within nested columns.

The third expression has been typed completely differently.  Now, we have a *Struct* instead of an *Association*, and content elements are now a mixture of vectors and associations.  The visualizer has decided that this heterogeneous collection of data comprises a *document* (in the sense of a ragged hierarchichal JSON or XML document).  Furthermore, it has made the conservative decision to display the second and third elements in elided form to save space.  But the first element is still being shown in a nested column, just like in the first example.

From these three examples, we can see that the heuristics are complicated and make it difficult to predict the outcome for even apparently simple expressions.

**More Examples**

Here are a few more examples to illustrate some of the kinds of heuristics that are applied.

*Dimensionality of association values*

```
{ <| "a" -> {{1, 2, 3}} |>
, <| "a" -> {1, 2, 3} |>
} // showShapes
```

[image: showShapes output]

*Vector length*

```
{ Range[5]
, Range[8]
, Range[9]
, Range[50]
, Range[51]
} // showShapes
```

[image: showShapes output]

*Tensor element count, dimensionality and raggedness*

```
{ {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8}}
, {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}
, Array[Times, {2,2,2}]
, Array[Times, {3,2,2}]
, Array[Times, {2,2,2,2}]
} // showShapes
```

[image: showShapes output]

**Yet another source of heuristics: type inferencing**

It is frequently the case that the visualization chosen for a `Dataset` is disturbed by a seemingly unrelated operation.  For example, consider this dataset:

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

We then apply an elaborate identity operation:

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][If[AbsoluteTime[] > 0, #, ""] &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

What happened?  When we apply operators to a dataset, the visualization chosen is based upon the data type of the final result.  However, that data type is *not* discovered by examining the final expression itself (so-called *type deduction*).  Rather, the data type is determined by applying some type algebra upon the initial data type and the applied query operators (*type inference*).  Type inferencing is far more difficult to perform than type deduction and often fails (resulting in a generic or unknown resultant type).

That is why the identity operator in the example was so elaborate.  It was chosen explicitly to fool the type inferencer.  Notice:

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}] // Dataset`GetType
(* Vector[Atom[Integer], 3] *)

Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][If[AbsoluteTime[]>0, #, ""]&] // Dataset`GetType
(* AnyType *)
```

*Work-around*

We can force the type deducer to rescan the final query result by adding an additional `Dataset` operator to the end of the query:

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][If[AbsoluteTime[]>0, #, ""]& /* Dataset]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

```
Dataset[{1, 2, 3}][If[AbsoluteTime[]>0, #, ""]& /* Dataset] // Dataset`GetType
(* Vector[Atom[Integer], 3] *)
```

As contrived as this example may be, type inference failure is actually quite a common occurrence.  The trailing `Dataset` operator work-around will often fix up the visualization.

**Bug?**

There can be no doubt that inconsistent visualization is inconvenient.  The third example is particularly strange and can surely be classified as a bug.  However, I hope this post has shown that the visualization problem is a difficult one, particularly in a type-fluid language such as *Mathematica*.  Such bugs, especially in corner cases, are pretty inevitable.

---

---

**Appendix: *showShapes***

The following definition of `showShapes` uses undocumented features that are current in version 11.1.0.  Note that it also adjusts some visualization properties in a manner that reduces the output to a size that is more compatible with the constraints of an *MSE* posting.

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
Needs["Dataset`"]
Needs["TypeSystem`"]

showShapes[exprs_List] :=
  Block[{ $ContextPath = Append[$ContextPath, "TypeSystem`PackageScope`"]
        , Dataset`$DatasetTargetRowCount = 5
        }
  , exprs
    // Query[All
       , { PrettyForm
         , Style[Dataset[#], Magnification->0.75]&
         , DeduceType /* PrettyForm
         , TypeSystem`PackageScope`chooseShape /* PrettyForm
         }
       ]
    // Prepend[#, {"Expression", "Dataset", "Type", "Shape"}]&
    // Grid[#, Frame -> All, Alignment -> {Left, Top}]&
    // Style[#, 11]&
    // Print
  ]
```

Comment: +1. Thank you for a very thorough explanation of behavior, that quite confused me. Your answer also catches my eye in its elegant formatting of code - most listings I see look like aiming at one-liner contests or follow Tufte's info per ink maximization scheme, that imo rather misses the point of "human legible code".