# Delete column from a dataset in mathematica

Tags: dataset, column

[image: data]

Hi, can anyone help me with this? I want to delete the column "FIPS" and "Admin2", and keep the dataset as the original. How would I do this?

```
data = Import[
  "C:\\Users\\49176\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\time_series_covid19_confirmed_\
US(2).csv", "Dataset", HeaderLines -> 1]
```

Code is here, and the csv file is downloaded from https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series

Comment: “ and keep the dataset as the original” - so you do not want to modify the original dataset, you just want to create a new one with those columns dropped?

Comment: My bad, I want to modify the dataset, not keep it as original

Comment: Please provide the Mathematica code for your `Dataset`. (Also, please keep the image because of [the answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/235814) by @kglr .)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of that. I have provided the code and the resource of the csv file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`KeyDrop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyDrop.html):

```
picture = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7ax0.jpg"];

table = Transpose[Partition[TextRecognize[picture, "Word"], 9] /. "Long_" -> "Long"];

ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[First @ table, #] & /@ Rest[table]]
```

[image]

```
KeyDrop[{"FIPS", "Admin2"}] @ ds
```

[image]

We also get the same result using any of the following:

```
ds[KeyDrop[{"FIPS", "Admin2"}]]

Query[KeyDrop[{"FIPS", "Admin2"}]] @ ds

ds[All, Delete[{{"FIPS"}, {"Admin2"}}]]

ds[All, Delete[{{1}, {2}}]]
```

Comment: Thank you! It is really helpful!

Comment: @jfm, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: Nice use of `TextRecognize`!

Comment: This looks like it generates a new dataset with the column dropped, is that right? Is there any way to drop the column 'in place', i.e. without copying over the entire dataset? That is, the only way to have the column deleted here is for one to do 'ds=ds[KeyDrop[{"FIPS", "Admin2"}]]'. (But I can see that this isn't the question in the OP.)

Comment: @berniethejet, see [this answer by WRech](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146177/125) re modification in place and `Dataset`.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {
   <|"a" -> 1, "b" -> "b1", "c" -> {1}, "d" -> 1, "e" -> {1}, 
    "f" -> 1|>,
   <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> "b2", "c" -> {2}, "d" -> 2, "e" -> {2}, 
    "f" -> 2|>,
   <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> "b3", "c" -> {3}, "d" -> 3, "e" -> {3}, 
    "f" -> 3|>,
   <|"a" -> 4, "b" -> "b4", "c" -> {4}, "d" -> 4, "e" -> {4}, 
    "f" -> 4|>,
   <|"a" -> 5, "b" -> "b5", "c" -> {5}, "d" -> 5, "e" -> {5}, 
    "f" -> 5|>,
   <|"a" -> 6, "b" -> "b6", "c" -> {6}, "d" -> 6, "e" -> {6}, 
    "f" -> 6|>};
list // Dataset
list[[All, 3 ;; 6]] // Dataset
```

[image]