# Unstable Dataset Formatting

Tags: output-formatting, dataset

I have a list of associations data set. If I do a simple `Mean[]` with [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) on two columns, I get a nice tidy table display.

```
dataset[GroupBy["Charge"],  GroupBy["Apodization"], Mean, specs]
```

[image]

But if I replace `Mean[]` with my own function `myMean[]`, I get a totally different, and quite redundant, table display. What's going on!?

```
myMean[list_] := Mean[list]

dataset[GroupBy["Charge"], GroupBy["Apodization"], myMean, specs]
```

[image]

The actual [`Dataset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) is at [www.dropbox.com/s/zld9dv34iuomnoz/gdd.m?dl=0](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zld9dv34iuomnoz/gdd.m?dl=0)

```
Get["https://www.dropbox.com/s/zld9dv34iuomnoz/gdd.m?dl=1"]
```

or

```
Get["https://pastebin.com/raw/SfJ2n5D6"]
```

or you can get it by

```
dataset=Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
  Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/97yPG.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

and in case it isn't obvious

```
specs = {"D86Diameter", "NullSplitRadius", "AmplitudeRippleSD", 
   "AmplitudeRipplePP", "PhaseSlope", "PhaseErrorSigma", 
   "PhaseErrorPP"};
```

Comment: I've reproduced this oddity with a random list-of-associations dataset, so I'm pretty sure it's not related to my particular dataset, specifically. It doesn't seem to happen with small names, but as the names get longer suddenly the behavior appears. Weird.

Comment: Welcome! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence. Thanks for including a **minimal working example** of code and data. In the future try to use the **[formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: Please provide the definition of `specs` since it might be relevant for the answer.  In the meantime, try changing the first query operator to `GroupBy["Charge"] /* Dataset` as a work-around.  Erratic dataset formatting is also discussed in [(146177)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146177/142) and [(143413)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143413/142).

Comment: The definition of specs is just the column names, but I added it above. Changing the query as you suggest @WReach made no difference.

Comment: And now, with slightly different numbers the formatting has flipped around so I can't get the format with column names (specs) on top of the columns at all. I understand that some people think this Dataset visualization is just a "convenience" thing, like the visualization of Interpolation, but if that's the case, why the heck is it so darn pretty!? It's such a tease -- beautifully formatted tables of your data .... juuuuust out of reach :)

Comment: I think [146177](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146177/142) says it best with the phrase: "These two constructs have the same Normal, but they are displayed differently." And this issue appears to be discussed in length [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143413/why-are-empty-lists-not-consistently-formatted-in-a-dataset/143551#143551)

Comment: @WReach, I can't replicate your `GroupBy["Charge"] /* Dataset` workaround in 11.1 - format looks the same as OP's.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a good answer other than [143413](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143413/why-are-empty-lists-not-consistently-formatted-in-a-dataset/143551#143551), which states "Whether or not this is an outright bug is a matter of perspective."