# Dataset column stubs in query result

Tags: dataset

Suppose I have a dataset with a header row.

```
ds = 
  Dataset[AssociationThread[{"x", "y", "z"}, #] & /@ RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 3}]];
```

I want to construct the following dataset of means and variances.  Note the header row and the stub column.)

```
Dataset[<|"mean" -> Normal@ds[Mean], "var" -> Normal@ds[Variance]|>]
```

How can I construct that with a single query on `ds` (an no use of `Normal`)?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The query `ds[<|"mean" -> Mean[#], "var" -> Variance[#]|> &]` should give you the dataset you need, though the output doesn't format nicely for some reason. The formatting can be fixed by throwing an extra `Dataset` at it:

```
Dataset @ ds[<|"mean" -> Mean[#], "var" -> Variance[#]|> &]
```

Comment: +1 slightly shorter `Dataset @ ds[<|"mean" -> Mean, "var" -> Variance|>]`

Comment: @WReach So there is no query that can produce what I want directly?  I ctually started with this query, did not like the result, but did not consider applying `Dataset` to get what I want, and I confess that I do not understand why this changes anything.  (I.e., the underlying association structure seems to be identical, but for some reason the type system information is different and forces the different display.  What is the underlying principle?)

Comment: I initially tried the similar query suggested by @WReach, but I did not guess that "throwing an extra `Dataset` at it" could help.  Why does this matter?  (I.e., what is the underlying principle?)

Comment: As you note, the different appearances are due to different types.  Without the extra `Dataset`, the final type is determined by type _inferencing_.  With it, the type is determined by type _deduction_.  Both use heuristics but, empirically, type deduction tends to yield better results.  These issues are discussed at more length in [(143551)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143551/142) and [(87479)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87479/142).