# Dataset changes layout depending on value types

Tags: dataset

I've been looking to using datasets for the sometimes nice layout and scrolling possibilities.
However I've been trying to find a way to "force" the layout when using nested tables.
I can't find any and it also seems to depend on the type of the values.
Are there any ways described to force a layout?

As a simple example.

```
planets = ExampleData[{"Dataset", "Planets"}]
```

[image]

```
ReplacePart[planets, {{"Earth", "Moons", "Moon", "Mass"} ->2, {"Earth", "Moons", "Moon", "Radius"} ->2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not a solution, but related: [(134413)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143413/142).

Comment: I think the issue in this particular example is that the structure of the dataset changes from "list of similar objects" to "list of different objectes" (since the data types in the bottom example are not all the same) - thos causes a change from the typical table layout to one of "list of completely random things with no structure". I can't check at the moment, but if you look at the `InputForm` of your datasets, you should see a change in structre in the type argument

Comment: Switching back to Grid. This took me to much time. Hoping for better features in a near future :)